# Does skin picking cause skin cancer?

Tags: medications, dermatology, disorders

I was a skin picker (Dermatillomaniac) since several years ago. Of course I pick only the skin of my hand thumbs. I wish to quit it and I wish to know about two things here:

1. Does chronic skin picking cause skin cancer?
2. Which topical medicines is good for repairing damaged skin because of picking?

Answer (score 2):

From [Skin cancer causes and risk factors](https://www.cancercenter.com/cancer-types/skin-cancer/risk-factors#:%7E:text=Can%20skin%20picking%20cause%20cancer,the%20symptoms%20of%20skin%20cancer%3F) (cancercenter.com)

> **Can skin picking cause cancer?**
>
> Frequent skin picking, also called dermatillomania, may damage the skin, but researchers have not found a link between this habit and the development of skin cancer.

So it looks like the answer is no.

However I know of one skin condition [Epidermolysis bullosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidermolysis_bullosa), where the skin tends to get damaged a lot and they are at risk of getting Squamous Cell Carcinoma and other cancers.

Answer (score -1):

Skin cancer can be caused by excessive UV exposure from the sun or tanning beds. I used to have trouble popping pimples until I figured it out. I think it is necessary to address to the psychotherapist and the dermatologist. Or at least use wound healing pharmaceutical preparations